# Alias for specific resourceful route's action ("/sign_in" instead of "/sessions/new")

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3, alias

I set up restful authentication and user management without any gems in Rails 3.

However, I think it's silly to need to go to "/sessions/new" instead of "/sign_in".

I know you can alias an entire resource, so that instead of "/sessions"-and-friends my users could use "/squirrels"-and-friends, but that's **not** what I'm trying to accomplish here. I want to alias one specific action.

I know this can *kind of* be accomplished with

```
resources :sessions, :path_names => { :new => "sign_in" }
```

but then the route ends up as "/sessions/sign_in" — and I don't want the controller name in there at all for this action. I wish I could specify this with

```
resources :sessions, :path_names => { :new => "/sign_in" }
```

where the "/" tells rails that it is a complete path name. But that has the same effect as the first code fragment.

My last attempt was just to use the superficial

```
match "sign_in" => "sessions#new"
```

which allows someone to manually enter "/sign_in" in their URL bar, but links made with `new_session_(path|url)` still land users at the more awkward "/sessions/sign_in".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
match "sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => :new_session
```

Comment: This lets you use "new_session_path" and gets rid of the "sign_in_path". Which is what I originally wanted to do.

Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of Rails you can no longer use match. Instead use the http verb.

Example:

```
get "sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => :new_session
```

Note that i've used `get` instead of match.

Tested on Rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
map.sign_in '/sign_in', :controller => 'session', :action => 'new'
```

To your `config/routes.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
match "sign_in" => "sessions#new"
```

line creates a route called "sign_in" which you can use in place of "new_session". So anywhere you had been linking to things with "new_session_path", replace it with "sign_in_path".

That's good enough. What I was originally hoping to do would be nice, though--to have "new_session_path" link to the same thing as "sign_in_path". To be able to specify a path_name that doesn't include the controller in it. Then I wouldn't need the `match` line at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about the "path" attribute? This should do what you want.

```
devise_for :users,
path: '',
controllers: {
  sessions: "user/sessions",
  passwords: "user/passwords",
  confirmations: "user/confirmations",
  registrations: "user/registrations"
},
path_names: {
  sign_in: "login",
  sign_out: "logout",
}
```